# Is there way to display Toast message in specific location?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Using Delphi Tokyo and the component TFMXToast I display a toast message like this:

```
FMXToast1.ToastMessage := 'my message';
FMXToast1.Show(self);
```

This appear in the form bottom , is there a way to change the message location ?

Comment: The answer is in this [fancy animation](https://github.com/zhaoyipeng/FMXComponents/blob/master/SnapShots/FMXToast.gif).

Comment: @Victoria thanks I will download the demos and see how it is done !!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Victoria

```
//Top position
FMXToast1.Align := TTextAlign.Leading

//Center
FMXToast1.Align := TTextAlign.Center

//Bottom
FMXToast1.Align := TTextAlign.Trailing
```

Comment: Honestly, I don't think that the `TTextAlign` type used by the author of that component for the position alignment property (instead of `TAlignLayout`) was a good choice.